# Displaying a list of all the content types

Tags: views

I need to display a list of all the content types which links to their respective page, displaying the contents of that type.

I tried a bunch of wild guesses like $row->content and couldn't manage.

How should I achieve this?

Comment: you can use view contectual filter to show only contents of a certain content type.

Comment: Nice question, I will be following this for a better answer.

One way to achive this task create a vocabulary named content types and include all your content types as terms in that vocabulary.

Using views contextual filter display all terms

Answer (score 1):

I have done something similar using *Views* and the *Summary* option for *Contextual filters*. 
I added the Content Type as a contextual filter with the following options:

[image]

The end result was a view that displays the following, if you have not specified a Content Type in the URL as an argument:

[image]

The only issue I found is that I won't display *Content Types* that have no content.

Answer (score 0):

You can probably extract the content types from the node entities (in code they are called bundles). But then you'll never know if there is a dedicated page for them. Therefor I'd recommend taking the following approach:

I'd create a new menu for this. Then make views pages for all the content types and in the views settings add the page to the menu. A little bit more work, but more control.

The menu can then be displayed in a sidebar, or other place.

Answer (score -1):

create a view for every content type that lists all the contents of that type. now create a web page and make a link for every view.